# duplicate same following elements in array

Tags: c, arrays, realloc, function-definition

I should build a function that gets an array and it's size and return a pointer
to new array (i need do create new array by using malloc and realloc) that find the identical numbers and duplicates them in the row
for example the array:{1,8,8,70,2,2,2,5,5,2} and size 10 suppose to return a pointer to this array
{1,8,8,8,8,70,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,2}. Any clue what's wrong with my code??

```
int * duplicateArray(int* arr, int n)

{
    int g = 1;
    int i,j=0;
    int *p = (int*)(calloc)(n, sizeof(int));
    assert(p);
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
        {
             p= (int*)(realloc)(p, n+g * sizeof(int));
             n=n+g;
             assert(p);
             p[j] = arr[i];
             j++;
             p[j] = arr[i+1];
        }
        else
            p[j] = arr[i];
        j++;
    }
   return p;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, i change it but stil it doesn't work

Comment: The function prototype `int * duplicateArray(int* arr, int n)` does not seem meaningful, as the calling function has no way of knowing the size of the returned array when using that function prototype.

Comment: If you use the function prototype `void duplicateArray ( const int *p_input_array, int num_input, int **pp_output_array, int *p_num_output )` instead, the function `duplicateArray` can write the address of the new array to `*pp_output_array` and the number of elements in the array to `*p_num_output`. That way, the calling function will effectively be able to receive two "return values" instead of only one.

Comment: What is the point of your variable `g`? It always has the value `1` and never changes?

Comment: The expression `n+g * sizeof(int)` is equivalent to `n + (g*sizeof(int))`. You probably want to write `(n+g) * sizeof(int)` instead. See [C operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: The loop `for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)` will not count from `0` to `n-2`, because `n` is increasing too. Whenever a duplicate is found, the line `n=n+g;` increments `n`. This means that the expression `arr[i + 1]` could still access the array out of bounds, because `i` may be larger than the original value of `n` minus 2.

Comment: If the parameter `n` is `1`, then your program will allocate an array for `1` element of type `int`, but will write nothing to it. It won't copy anything from the input buffer.

Comment: You are also accessing the output array `p` out of bounds, which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This is also the case if you write `(n+g) * sizeof(int)` instead of `n+g * sizeof(int)`, as I have previously suggested. This is because your loop has more than `n-1` iterations, because in the loop, you are increasing `n`. This causes undefined behavior and causes the `printf` call to crash on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach used by you when the memory is constantly reallocated is inefficient.

Also the function should return not only the pointer to the dynamically allocated array but also the number of elements in the allocated array. Otherwise the user of the function will not know how many elements are in the allocated array. To use a sentinel value for an integer dynamically allocated array is not a good idea.

I suggest to split the task into two separate tasks that will correspond to two separate functions..

The first function will count the number of repeated elements in a given array.

The second function will create dynamically an array with the specified size based on the returned value of the first function and copy elements of the source array to the newly created array.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t countRepeated( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t repeated = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i != n;  )
    {
        size_t m = 1;

        while ( ++i != n && a[i] == a[i-1] ) ++m;

        if ( m != 1 ) repeated += m;
    }

    return repeated;
}

int * copyWithDuplication( const int a[], size_t n, size_t m )
{
    int *result = m == 0 ? NULL : calloc( m, sizeof( int ) );

    if ( result )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; j != m && i != n;  )
        {
            result[j++] = a[i++];

            size_t k = 1;

            while ( j != m && i != n && a[i] == a[i-1] )
            {
                result[j++] = a[i++];
                ++k;
            }                   

            if ( k != 1 )
            {
                while ( j != m && k-- ) result[j++] = a[i-1];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 8, 8, 70, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t m = N + countRepeated( a, N );

    int *b = copyWithDuplication( a, N, m );

    if ( b )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", b[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( b );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 8 8 70 2 2 2 5 5 2 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 2
```

And here is another more interesting demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t countRepeated( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t repeated = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i != n;  )
    {
        size_t m = 1;

        while ( ++i != n && a[i] == a[i-1] ) ++m;

        if ( m != 1 ) repeated += m;
    }

    return repeated;
}

int * copyWithDuplication( const int a[], size_t n, size_t m )
{
    int *result = m == 0 ? NULL : calloc( m, sizeof( int ) );

    if ( result )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; j != m && i != n;  )
        {
            result[j++] = a[i++];

            size_t k = 1;

            while ( j != m && i != n && a[i] == a[i-1] )
            {
                result[j++] = a[i++];
                ++k;
            }                   

            if ( k != 1 )
            {
                while ( j != m && k-- ) result[j++] = a[i-1];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 8, 8, 70, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t m = N + countRepeated( a, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        int *b = copyWithDuplication( a, N, i + 1 );

        if ( b )
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ )
            {
                printf( "%d ", b[j] );
            }
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        free( b );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 8 8 70 2 2 2 5 5 2 
1 
1 8 
1 8 8 
1 8 8 8 
1 8 8 8 8 
1 8 8 8 8 70 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 2 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 2 2 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 2 2 2 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 
1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 2
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could allocate a new buffer that is double the size of the input array (because it will never need to be more than double size) and then shrink that array afterwards using `realloc`. That way, you won't need two functions.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It is not a flexible approach. When you have two functions you can for example copy the source array in the destination array of the same size or even in an array that has the size  that is less than the size of the source array. Here is the result array when its size is the same as the size of the source array 1 8 8 8 8 70 2 2 2 2

Comment: I have now provided my algorithm as an alternative answer. However, you are right that your algorithm is more flexible. Therefore, I have upvoted your answer. My solution only works because there is an upper-bound on the total size of the output buffer, which is double the size of the input buffer.

Answer (score 1):

> Any clue what's wrong with my code??

If the parameter `n` is `1`, then your program will allocate an array for `1` element of type `int`, but will write nothing to it. It won't copy anything from the input buffer.

You are accessing both the input `arr` and the output array `p` out of bounds, which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The loop

`for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)`

will not count from 0 to the function parameter `n` minus `2`, because `n` is being incremented inside the loop. This causes your loop to have more iterations than it is supposed to, which causes both the input and the output array to be accessed out of bounds.

Also, there doesn't seem to be much point in your variable `g`, as it never changes and always has the value `1`.

The [function prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype)

`int * duplicateArray(int* arr, int n);`

does not seem meaningful, as the calling function has no way of knowing the size of the returned array. If you use the function prototype

`void duplicateArray ( const int *p_input_array, int num_input, int **pp_output_array, int *p_num_output );`

instead, the function `duplicateArray` can write the address of the new array to `*pp_output_array` and the number of elements in the array to `*p_num_output`. That way, the calling function will effectively be able to receive two "return values" instead of only one.

Here is my implementation of the function `duplicateArray` and also of the calling function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

void duplicateArray( const int *p_input_array, int num_input, int **pp_output_array, int *p_num_output )
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    // In the most extreme case, the output array must be 2 times larger than
    // the input buffer, so we allocate double the size of the input buffer.
    int *p_output_array = (int*)malloc( num_input * 2 * sizeof(int) );
    assert( p_output_array != NULL );

    while ( i < num_input )
    {
        int num_repetitions;

        int k = p_input_array[i++];

        //count the number of repetitions
        for ( num_repetitions = 0; i < num_input && p_input_array[i] == k; num_repetitions++, i++ );

        if ( num_repetitions == 0 )
        {
            p_output_array[j++] = k;
        }
        else
        {
            for ( int l = 0; l < num_repetitions + 1; l++ )
            {
                p_output_array[j++] = k;
                p_output_array[j++] = k;
            }
        }
    }

    //shrink the array to the actually needed size
    p_output_array = (int*)realloc( p_output_array, j * sizeof(int) );
    assert( p_output_array != NULL );

    *pp_output_array = p_output_array;
    *p_num_output = j;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 8, 8, 70, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2 };
    int *p;
    int num;

    duplicateArray( arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr), &p, &num );

    for ( int i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
        printf( "%d\n", p[i] );
    }

    free( p );
}
```